# woocommerce pull data into a dynamic dropdown list form

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, dynamic

Trying to extract data into a dropdown list but no results are showing

```
  <form method="POST" action="city_processProduct.php?action=cityDest">

  <td class="label" align="center">
  <?php  global $wpdb;
  // get all countries
  $sql1 = "SELECT city_countries_country
           FROM city_callingfrom_countries
           ORDER BY city_countries_country";
  $result1 = $wpdb->get_results($sql1);
  ?>
  <select name="dest[]" size="5" multiple>
  <?php global $wpdb;
  while($row1 = $wpdb->get_results($result1)) {
    extract($row1);
    echo"<option value='$row1->$city_countries_country</option> ";
  }
  ?>
  </select>
  </form>
```

However when i  echo db table row without form it gets results

```
<?php  global $wpdb;
  $sql1 = $wpdb->get_results ("SELECT city_countries_country
           FROM city_countries
           ORDER BY city_countries_country");
      foreach ($sql1 as $result){
      echo  "$result->city_countries_country</br>";
      }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an orphan table cell in your form code. If the dropdown is supposed to be a table cell the td should be above the form tag. Make sure you close the cell also.

Answer (score 0):

There is issue in HTML formatting. The td tag should come before the FORM tag and td should also close right after the form tag to display properly.